# installed python3 module not found runtime

Tags: python, uwsgi

Having installed (with `sudo pip install uwsgi`) the python uwsgi module, I can find it with pip freeze (showing up as uWSGI ....). Running from uwsgi via my .ini file or directly with python3 (name of python file).py I'm told that import uwsgi results in module not found.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, python is 3.10(.6). The problem turned up after an apt upgrade.

it seems to be a rights problem or a path problem.

How do I proceed.

Peter Raabye

I have tried to reinstall uwsgi, the uwsgi module and even the python.

Comment: If you're on a machine that has both Python 2 and Python 3, it's possible that `pip` points to the Python 2 version.  Try `sudo -H python3 -m pip install uswgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Another reinstall later this problem has disappeared.

Comment: This would be more beneficial as a comment. Keep answers to longer more detailed responses.